# C++ Adding Two 16 bit binary numbers together

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, calculation, bit

I am trying to add two 16 digit binary numbers together. Each binary number will have been entered by the user and saved as: `int binaryOne[16] and int binaryTwo[16]`. Originally,

```
int binaryOne[16] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int binaryTwo[16] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

are the values declared. Then, the user has the option to change these values using buttons that I implement before the Solution() function. So, once the used gets to the Solution() function, the numbers may be stored as:

```
int binaryOne[16] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1};
int binaryTwo[16] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1};
```

This is what I have so far:

```
void Solution() {
  /*
    Rule of binary addition:
    0 + 0 = 0
    1 + 0 = 1
    0 + 1 = 1
    1 + 1 = 1 and carry = 1
   */
   lcd.clear();
   lcd.setCursor(0,0);
   lcd.print("Solution");
   lcd.setCursor(0,2);





    int a[16] = binaryOne[16];
    int b[16] = binaryTwo[16];
    int i = 0;
    int remainder = 0;
    int sum[32];

    while(a[16] != 0 || b[16] != 0){
      sum[i++] = (a[16] % 10 + b[16] % 10 + remainder) % 2;
      remainder = (a[16] % 10 + b[16] % 10 + remainder) / 2; 
      a[16] = a[16] /10;
      b[16] = b[16] / 10;
    }
    if(remainder != 0){
      sum[i++] = remainder;
    }
    i--;
    while(i>=0){
      lcd.print("%d", sum[i--]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I believe I am doing something wrong with calling the arrays since I am renaming them to a[16] and b[16] within this function. I'm also curious, since I only have 16 bits of space on the screen, what if the user enters a binary number such as 1111111111111111 + 1000000000000000 and therefor there is going to be a carry on that first digit? Would it be best just to have an error message?

Comment: Why not just turn the array bits into an int number, and then add them?

Comment: int result1 = (a[15]<<15) | (a[14]<<14) | ... (a[2]<<2) | (a[1]}<1) | a[0];

Comment: do the same for result2.  Probably better if both are unsigned int.

Comment: then  unsigned long = result1 + result2;

Comment: @CrossRoads I need to output the solution as a binary number, sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: You say "I am renaming them to a[16] and b[16]", but `int a[16] = binaryOne[16];` does not rename the array. When declaring an array, you have the option to initialize the array with a curly-braced list of values, or a string literal. Your code won't compile.

Comment: lcd.print(result, BIN)

Comment: @josecanuc I apologize, I added more description of the binaryOne and binaryTwo ints above for clarity on what I meant.

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that `int a[16] = binaryOne[16];` does not rename the array or copy the array from `binaryOne` to `a`. `int a[16]` declares an array of 16 `int`s. `binaryOne[16]` doesn't refer to anything, because `binaryOne` is defined as an array of 16 `int`s, indexed from 0 to 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a mountain out of a molehill.

You're trying to manually manipulate binary digits in an array, but C can already manipulate binary digits. Everything is binary already - you just need to represent it as such.

All you need to do is convert the contents of your array into an actual number, then do simple mathematics on that number.  One of the simplest ways of doing that is to shift the bits into a variable:

For instance:

```
int binaryOne[16] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1};
int binaryTwo[16] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1};

uint16_t binOne = 0;
uint16_t binTwo = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    binOne <<= 1;
    binOne |= binaryOne[i];
    binTwo <<= 1;
    binTwo |= binaryTwo[i];
}
```

Now you can add them together, since they're just numbers:

```
uint32_t result = binOne + binTwo;
```

And you can output it as binary:

```
Serial.println(result, BIN);
```

If you want to convert back into an array again (why?!) you can just do the opposite as before:

```
bool resultBin[32];

for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    resultBin[i] = (result & (1 << (31-i))) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: it is probably a school assignment

Comment: I tend to think things are a lot harder than they actually are unfortunately haha. I don't know why I didn't see this easy solution. Thank you!

Comment: Read the part of my answer that starts with: "And you can output it as binary..."

Comment: @Majenko Oh duh, it was right there, sorry. I will check your answer as accepted. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

A few issues here:

1. The way you “rename” the arrays is wrong, and furthermore there is no
   point in doing such renaming.
2. There is no reason to divide by 10 (ten, in decimal) within your
   code: as everything you do is binary, the number *ten* has nothing to
   do with what are trying to accomplish.
3. While doing the addition, you forgot to *loop* over the bits.
4. You shouldn't `return 0` in a function of type `void`. In fact, you
   shouldn't return any value.

Fixing those issues should give you something similar to this:

```
void Solution() {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Solution");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 2);

    // Compute the sum.
    int sum[16];
    int remainder = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        int s = binaryOne[i] + binaryTwo[i] + remainder;
        sum[i] = s % 2;
        remainder = s / 2;
    }

    // Print it.
    for (int i = 15; i >= 0; i--) {
        lcd.print("%d", sum[i]);
    }
}
```

Note that there is no point in computing a 32-bit result if you can only
print 16 bits: just accept that the computation is done modulo
2<sup>16</sup>, just like a 16-bit ALU would do, or the `unsigned int`
data type in the Arduino.

Of course, the whole idea of doing the computation one bit at a time is
highly inefficient. See Majenko's answer for a more idiomatic and
efficient way of managing numbers bit-wise in C and C++.